# How to convert string to integer in BIRT after fetching it from the database?

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt

I use BIRT for reports and i am a beginner BIRT user. In my report i must calculate the average of a column. (database is an oracle)

In my open script I have sth. like this:

```
sqlText = "select A, B, C, D, ((date1-date2) day to second) as differencedate from problem";
```

difference date column values are like this: 0 0:22:15 and in my fetch I have

```
if (!maximoDataSet.fetch())
    return (false);

row["A"] = maximoDataSet.getString("A");
row["B"] = maximoDataSet.getDate("B");
....    

row["differencedate"]=maximoDataSet.getString("differencedate");

return (true);
```

I tried to split the string and get the seconds from the differencedate and convert it to integer using plain JavaScript but I am getting an error like "split null" etc. So my question is how can i convert this column to integer in BIRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try retrieving the date difference from the database as a number - like so:

```
select A, B, C, D, 
       ((date1-date2) day to second) as differencedate,
       (date1-date2) * 86400 as differenceseconds
from problem
```

Comment: this also works for me, thanks. However I am curious, is it possible in BIRT to get all the elements from database (select * from mytable) and process it in javascript? for example multiply some integer columns by 4 and change the data of some rows etc. in fetch or open? Because using only one sql query is really hard for me to get the desired data.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Personally, I find it easier to do that sort of manipulation in SQL, than in Javascript. In many cases, it will also be more efficient to process large quantities of data on the DB server and then transfer the results to BIRT, than to transfer the raw data from the DB server and then do additional processing in BIRT.